# MaterializeCSS navbar unable to split col into two lines

Tags: html, css, materialize

Stuck trying to get a box with account information in the navbar of Materialize. Pretty sure is 2min work for experienced CSS but I am already stuck into this for several hours.

What I have:
[image]

What I want is to have the IP and Country inside the navbar on different lines. Currently, it jumps out to the body HTML otuside the navbar :(

This is my code:

```
<nav class="blue-grey darken-4">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col s8"></div>
        <div class="col s2">
            <div class="row">
                <div id="ip_address" class="">IP:</div>
                <div id="country" class="col s5">Country:</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
```

Any help appreciated. Thanks!